# Windows Open SSH Server cannot support more than 50 concurrent ssh sessions

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to set up a Windows OpenSSH Server (v1.0.0.0-Beta) and I've hit a problem.

I have a program that uses plink to create ssh connections. This can range from 1-200 connections and I'm pretty sure that should be safe. However, when I've made 50, **EXACTLY 50** ssh connections, the ssh server starts rejecting the connections and looking at the logs, it shows that the posix_spawn failed and it can no longer instantiate child processes to handle the connections

I've tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472389/how-to-increase-the-maximum-number-of-child-processes-that-can-be-spawned-by-a-w) and it didn't do anything for it. I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Here is the error log when the 51st connection is made

```
1656 2018-03-05 16:08:05.610 debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
1656 2018-03-05 16:08:05.610 debug3: spawning "C:\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe" "-R"
1656 2018-03-05 16:08:05.610 error: posix_spawn failed
1656 2018-03-05 16:08:05.610 debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 357
1656 2018-03-05 16:08:05.610 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
1656 2018-03-05 16:08:05.610 debug3: send_rexec_state: done
1656 2018-03-05 16:08:05.610 debug3: ReadFileEx() ERROR:109, io:00000010C2BF98B0
```

Here is my config

```
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe
LogLevel Debug3
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
MaxStartups 1000
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitTTY yes
PidFile C:/ProgramData/ssh/sshd.pid
MaxSessions 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I opened an issue for this in their github page and got an unfortunate answer,

Apparently this is a hardcoded limit in their code since windows can't have more handles per thread and they don't want to go multi threaded and make it more complicated. I've attached a link below to the github issue

Here's their response

> Ultimately, all these child process handles will be fed in a WaitForMultipleObjects call (as part of wait_for_any_event()) and that Win32 API call has a limitation of 64 handles. I had to pick a number less than this to accommodate other events (that of async accept and connect calls). Going beyond these limits will result in multi a threaded POSIX compat layer that will make it more complex and less resilient.

[Github Link](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1096)

Answer (score 0):

Bitvise SSH can potentially handle more than 50 concurrent users: https://fogbugz.bitvise.com/default.asp?WinSSHD.1.7313.1

Dont belong to BitVise, but have tried OpenSSH from MS, MobaSSH, and BitVise SSH server had the best experience out of the box